# Text Processing in R finding words

Tags: r

I am looking for efficient way to code the below . I am looking for anything that contains add and onion in the text then it is Found and if it is not there then it not found. I want to get this in an efficient manner. I dont want to hard code all the combination in it . I am looking for if add and onion are there in the text then it is found.

````
word_check <- c("add get onion" ,
                 "add to onion",
                "add oil to onion",
                "add oils to onion" ,
                "add salt to onion" ,
                "add get onion" ,
                "add get onion", 
                "add get onion")

df <- as.data.frame(c("I can add get onion" ,
                      "we can add to onion",
                      "I love to add oil to onion",
                      "I may not add oils to onion" ,
                      "add salt to onion" ,
                      "add get onion" ,
                      "abc",
                      "def" ,
                      "ghi",
                      "jkl",
                      "add get onion", 
                      "add get onion","add oil to the vegetable", "add onion to the vegetable" ))
names(df)[1] <- "text"


pattern_word_check <- paste(word_check, collapse = "|")


df$New <- ifelse(str_detect(df$text, regex(pattern_word_check)),"Found","Not Found")```

Regards, R
````

Comment: In the previous question , I was looking for individual words , here I am looking for two words and any thing can come in between.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood so I propose you when solution based on your `pattern_word_check` variable and another using only *onion* and *add* in the regex.

Anyway, I think you are looking for `grepl`. You have many ways to solve your problem.

## data.table

A `data.table` solution, using conditional replacement, would be :

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,'new' := "Not Found"]
df[grepl(pattern_word_check, text), new := "Found"]
```

If you only want to consider words with *"onion"* **OR** *"add"*

```r
df[,'new' := "Not Found"]
df[grepl("(onion|add)", text), new := "Found"]
```

## dplyr

A `dplyr` solution would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(new = if_else(grepl(pattern_word_check, text), "Found", "Not Found"))
```

Note that if use `if_else` from `dplyr` package, not base `ifelse`.

If you only want to consider words with *"onion"* **OR** *"add"*

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(new = if_else(grepl("(onion|add)", text), "Found", "Not Found"))
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. I am looking for if the text contains add first and then at any place if onion comes then it should be found . eg : I like to eat something , good, lets add something to the vegetables dont forget to add onions into it. I am not looking for using or . Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to check for only `"onion"` and `"add"` which can occur in any order, you could do.

```
df$New <- ifelse(grepl('.*add.*onion.*|.*onion.*add.*',df$text), "found", "not found")
#Faster option without ifelse
#df$New <- c('Not found', 'found')[grepl('.*add.*onion.*|.*onion.*add.*', df$text) + 1]
df

#                          text       New
#1          I can add get onion     found
#2          we can add to onion     found
#3   I love to add oil to onion     found
#4  I may not add oils to onion     found
#5            add salt to onion     found
#6                add get onion     found
#7                          abc not found
#8                          def not found
#9                          ghi not found
#10                         jkl not found
#11               add get onion     found
#12               add get onion     found
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak for your suggestions , this might not work for me as if the text has only Onion or  add , even then it is found. I am looking if the string has both add and onion . I would appreciate if I can do that with str_detect. Regards, R

Comment: `this might not work for me as if the text has only Onion or add` and `I am looking if the string has both add and onion` these two sentences are opposite of each other and don't mean the same. Please confirm what exactly you want to do. Perhaps you need `df$New <- ifelse(str_detect(df$text, 'oil|onion'), "Found", "Not found")`

Comment: I am looking for if the text contains add first and then at any place if onion comes then it should be found . eg : I like to eat something , good, lets add something to the vegetables dont forget to add onions into it.

Comment: @RBan `df$New <- ifelse(str_detect(df$text, 'oil|onion'), "Found", "Not found")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `tidytext`. For your concrete example, this may seem a bit like overkill, but using more highlevel functions like a tokenizer together with an `inner_join` makes the code more clear and easier to build on. (imo)

```r
df <- as.data.frame(c("I can add get onion" ,
                      "we can add to onion",
                      "I love to add oil to onion",
                      "I may not add oils to onion" ,
                      "add salt to onion" ,
                      "add get onion" ,
                      "abc",
                      "def" ,
                      "ghi",
                      "jkl",
                      "add get onion", 
                      "add get onion","add oil to the vegetable", "add onion to the vegetable" ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df)[1] <- "text"
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
df_words <- df %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = word,
                input = text,
                 token = "words",
                drop = FALSE)
inner_join(
  df_words %>% filter(word == "add"),
  df_words %>% filter(word == "onion"),
  by = "text"
) %>% 
  select(text) %>% 
  distinct()
#>                          text
#> 1         I can add get onion
#> 2         we can add to onion
#> 3  I love to add oil to onion
#> 4 I may not add oils to onion
#> 5           add salt to onion
#> 6               add get onion
#> 7  add onion to the vegetable
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>